# Airflow snowflake connection not appearing in UI

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow-connections

I have set up airflow 2.5.1 on docker.
pip freeze in scheduler, worker and webserver:

```
apache-airflow==2.5.1
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==4.0.4
snowflake==0.0.3
snowflake-connector-python==3.0.2
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.4.7
sqlalchemy==1.4.46

python --version is 3.7.16
```

From documentation, requirements:
The package supports the following python versions: 3.7,3.8,3.9,3.10

```
apache-airflow >=2.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql >=1.3.1
snowflake-connector-python>=2.4.1
snowflake-sqlalchemy >=1.1.0
```

However, the connection type for snowflake is not showing in UI.

Please advise